# Canvas Clip function bug on Galaxy Nexus

Tags: android, android-canvas, ondraw

I'm making a application it's picture cropping.
But Galaxy nexus has some problem.
Region.Op.DIFFERENCE is not works.
Desire(2.3.3) and GalaxyNexus(4.1) Emulator works well. 
But not works only on GalaxyNexus Real Phone

[image: Desire (2.3.3) works well]

[image: Galaxy Nexus (4.1.1) problem]

Please see the code...
It's a onDraw overrided method it's extended imageview

```
@override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    //all rectangle   
    getDrawingRect(viewRect);

    //small rectangle
    getDrawingRect(smallRect);
    smallRect.left += 100;
    smallRect.right -= 100;
    smallRect.bottom -= 200;
    smallRect.top += 200;

    // paint  color setting to transparency black
    mNoFocusPaint.setARGB(150, 50, 50, 50);

    // All Rectangle clipping
    canvas.clipRect(viewRect);
    // Small Rectangle clipping
    canvas.clipRect(smallRect, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);

    // Draw All Rectangle transparency black color it's except small rectangle
    canvas.drawRect(viewRect, mNoFocusPaint);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

solved!

add this code in manifest

```
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

: )

Answer (score 2):

JuHyun's answer is great! In my case however I didn't want to remove hardware acceleration for my entire app across all SDK versions. The issue with hardware-accelerated canvas clipping seems to be confined to 4.1.1, so I took the route of disabling hardware acceleration for the specific view in which I was performing the clipping operation.

Custom view class (in this case, a RecyclerView):

```
public class ClippableRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {

    private final CanvasClipper clipper = new CanvasClipper();

    public ClippableRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        configureHardwareAcceleration();
    }

    public ClippableRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        configureHardwareAcceleration();
    }

    public ClippableRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        configureHardwareAcceleration();
    }

    public void configureHardwareAcceleration() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Remove the region from the current clip using a difference operation
     * @param rect
     */
    public void removeFromClipBounds(Rect rect) {
        clipper.removeFromClipBounds(rect);
        invalidate();
    }

    public void resetClipBounds() {
        clipper.resetClipBounds();
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        super.onDraw(c);
        clipper.clipCanvas(c);
    }
}
```

Canvas clipper class:

```
public class CanvasClipper {

    private final ArrayList<Rect> clipRegions = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * Remove the region from the current clip using a difference operation
     * @param rect
     */
    public void removeFromClipBounds(Rect rect) {
        clipRegions.add(rect);
    }

    public void resetClipBounds() {
        clipRegions.clear();
    }

    public void clipCanvas(Canvas c) {
        if (!clipRegions.isEmpty()) {
            for (Rect clipRegion : clipRegions) {
                c.clipRect(clipRegion, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```